# Creating an OSX application without Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm very new to OS X, and I'm trying to create a simple application without Xcode. I did found some other sites doing that, but I cannot attach event handlers to my button.

below is the code (crafted from other sites). It creates a window and a button, but I don't know how to attach that event to the button:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface myclass
-(void)buttonPressed;
@end

@implementation myclass

-(void)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"Button pressed!"); 

    //Do what You want here... 
    NSAlert *alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Hi there."];
    [alert runModal];
}


@end



int main ()
{
    [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
    id menubar = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem new] autorelease];
    [menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
    [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
    id appMenu = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];
    id appName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];
    id quitTitle = [@"Quit " stringByAppendingString:appName];
    id quitMenuItem = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:quitTitle
        action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"] autorelease];
    [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
    [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
    id window = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200)
        styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO]
            autorelease];


    [window cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:NSMakePoint(20,20)];
    [window setTitle:appName];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

    int x = 10; 
    int y = 100; 

    int width = 130;
    int height = 40; 

    NSButton *myButton = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(x, y, width, height)] autorelease];
    [[window contentView] addSubview: myButton];
    [myButton setTitle: @"Button title!"];
    [myButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryLightButton]; //Set what type button You want
    [myButton setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle]; //Set what style You want


    [myButton setAction:@selector(buttonPressed)];


    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [NSApp run];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Do you mean with Xcode altogether (which is a weird requirement) or without using Interface Builder (which is quite common)?

Comment: If you're new to OS X it would be wise to use Xcode and Interface Builder until you are knowledgeable enough to understand how it works under the surface.

Comment: Isn't Xcode free on the App Store?

Comment: Xcode is Free and is definitely recommended for beginners. It would require substantial knowledge of Objective-c and Cocoa to create GUI apps without Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't avoid Xcode because you are a beginner. Being a beginner is one of the many reasons to use Xcode. Resorting to fully-manually-implemented code like what you have is a naive way to develop applications for OS X and you'll only encounter far more difficulties than it is worth, especially for anything non-trivial.

Having said that, the reason your button isn't doing anything is because the button doesn't have a target. All actions require a target. In your case, you want to create an instance of your `myclass` class (note that class names in Objective-C are conventionally named in upper camelcase, i.e. `MyClass`). Note that also your action method should take an argument (which is the sender of the action), even if it is unused.

```
- (void) buttonPressed:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Button pressed!"); 

    //Do what You want here... 
    NSAlert *alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Hi there."];
    [alert runModal];
}

// ...

myclass *mc = [[myclass alloc] init];

[myButton setTarget:mc];
[myButton setAction:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
```

I can't stress enough how ridiculous all of this code is. Bite the bullet and dive into Xcode!